# Is there a purpose for the concrete border at base of this house?

Tags: concrete, foundation

My wife and I are in negotiations to purchase a house that is located in the Southeastern US.  The home inspector was a bit baffled by the concrete border (first image) that runs along the back and one side of the house.  At 4 or 5 locations there are steel plates (second image) about 12" wide butted up against the concrete border.  Do these features look familiar to anyone?  The inspector seems to think that it is evidence of some sort of foundation work, but because the walk-out basement is fully finished, there is no way to inspect things from the inside.  Since I don't own the home I can't just start digging exploratory holes in the backyard either.

[image: Concrete Border]
[image: Steel Plate]

Comment: I'd guess they are trying to keep water away from the foundation from a leaky basement. If there aren't gutters above, this could also be a form of ground level gutters. At the very least, I'd ask the current homeowner what's up with them.

Comment: The house has full gutters.  Unfortunately, the current owner has only been in the house for 2 years and doesn't know anything about it.  I went so far as to check with the county to see if any permits were pulled for work on the house and nothing shows up.  A stucco inspection yesterday revealed some wet walls, one of which was directly above an area of the basement with a small area of water damage.  I suppose it is possible that a stucco problem was misdiagnosed as a foundation problem.